# How to open SQL file in new tab using same connection?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm switching to MySQL from SQL Server...

In Windows when I open a SQL file (from Windows explorer) with SQL Server Management Studio, it opens in a new tab of SSMS using the current (or latest) db connection and object explorer in use by SSMS .

But when I open the SQL file with MySQL Workbench, I'm presented with the graphical menu to choose the database connection, in which case a new database connection is opened in a "parent tab" with its own navigator pane, but if I open a new tab with ctrl-T from within there, another "query tab" opens with the same connection and navigator pane.

Is there a way to have MySQL Workbench open a new query window in the current connection when opening a SQL file from windows explorer, rather than open a new connection/navigator pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a workaround for folks like me who might want to select the SQL file from windows explorer rather than the open file dialog with MySQL Workbench:

You can drag the file from windows explorer into the current query window and it will open that file in a new query window using the same database connection.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Management Studio 2014 on windows 8, I had to edit my registry with the values below. Note, that the ddeexec *open* value **must** be lower case.

This node, sql_auto_file is the value pointed to by the HKCR.sql entry. So, your's may point to a different node, but the values under *shell* should follow the same pattern.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sql_auto_file]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sql_auto_file\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sql_auto_file\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sql_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio\\Ssms.exe\" /dde"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sql_auto_file\shell\open\DdeExec]
@="open(\"%1\")"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sql_auto_file\shell\open\DdeExec\Application]
@="ssms.12.0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sql_auto_file\shell\open\DdeExec\Topic]
@="system"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can open an sql file from within a query tab, staying so in the current SQL IDE instance (and connection). Opening from command line (which is what happens when you double click an sql file in Windows Explorer) only allows the way to select a connection and open the file in a new SQL IDE instance. However, if you already have the SQL IDE open, why do you detour to Windows Explorer to open sql files? Just open them from within MySQL Workbench via the open dialog, as you would do with evey other application that works with documents.